# I cannot perform "store.sync" in my Sencha? Proxy is getting data from a Salesforce Controller

Tags: mobile, salesforce1-app, salesforce-sencha

I have view that displays a list of records. When you click a record, a panel should pop up giving us a field "Status". I have accomplished it as below

```
'listeners : {
                        scope : this,<br>
                        itemtap : function(dataview, index, el, record, e){<br>

                            var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
                                alias: "widget.formpanelview",
                                 modal : true,
                                hideOnMaskTap : true,
                                centered : true,
                                scrollable : 'vertical',
                                layout: { type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch' },
                                items:[
                                {xtype: 'spacer'},
                                {
                                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                                    name: 'Status__c',
                                    label: 'Status',
                                    options: [ 
                                         //some options 
                                     ]
                                     },
                                     {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        //width : 100,
                                        text: 'Save',
                                        handler: function(){
                                            console.log('Inside Save');
                                            var InvStore = Ext.getStore('Investors');
                                            InvStore.sync();
                                            console.log('Completed Sync');
                                            formPanel.hide();
                                        }
                                     },
                                     {xtype: 'spacer'},
                                     {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        text: 'Cancel',
                                        itemId: 'cancel',
                                        //width : 100,
                                        handler: function(){
                                            formPanel.hide();
                                        }
                                     }]
                            });
                            formPanel.setRecord(record);
                            Ext.Viewport.add(formPanel).show();
                        }'
```

Cancel button works fine and hides the panel, save button executes fully and hides panel but data is not storing. I have given "Update" in my model for sync to execute.

```
proxy: {<br>
            type: 'direct',<br>
            api: {<br>
                read: PocketCRMAccountController.Query,<br>
                update: PocketCRMAccountController.Edit<br>
            }
```

What might be the cause for store not to execute?

I think I zero'd in on the problem. When I put a "Status" debug on the save method, It is showing the old value. It is not showing the changed value. I dont know why it is not showing the changed one. If it changes, Sync would work it seems. any help?

Comment: PLEASE try to use relevant tags only. Picking a collection of tags that are not specifically related to your question, may make it appear not related to salesforce and closed as off topic. Elaborating a bit more on the context and what you're trying to achieve/build overall may also help.

Comment: Can you show us your apex code?

Comment: @user320. Want me to show the controller code?

Comment: Yes please, all of it :-)

Comment: Sure @user320. Just give me some time, on the verge of a issue and can tell me how I could add a header to dataview?

Comment: instead of just Direct proxy, might be worth a shot using the Visualforce Remoting proxy for Sencha Touch: https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-touch-common/blob/master/src/data/proxy/VFRemote.js - will simplify your components and controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was that , I didn't update the value of status when "store.sync" was executed. It was a silly mistake but it taught me something. Hope this mistake helps others not to do that. Please debug your values before you update any store. I am closing this thread. Thank you for everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to the call the `InvStore.load()` after you do the syncing using `InvStore.sync()`

Also, are you using a writer to write to your store? Your proxy code looks incomplete. Force.com MVP Don Robins published a detailed tutorial which explains the concepts of proxy and store in detail. You can read it [here](http://www.sencha.com/blog/developing-mobile-applications-with-forcecom-and-sencha-touch-part-2/).

Comment: I have a writer to my store. I didn't give it above. Actually my sync is good but as I didn't change the value, sync saw no change in value. Anyway, thank you for providing your view.

Comment: Okay, in future, please provide the complete code snippet for reference so others can understand your issue fully. I am hoping your problem is resolved. If so, please close this thread.

Comment: Can you tell how could add a header to my dataview? I tried using a toolbar but as I have 5 columns, title is in center and Isn't helping. Any suggestions? @user320? Gaurav?

Comment: I would request you raise another question for that with proper citing of your UI code. It won't be useful for anyone else to discuss unrelated questions on this thread.